# Multiple dropdown menu filter in html using Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and trying to create a view where the user can have options to select the values. Can someone guide on how to proceed with it?

I have attached the model for your reference, the user should be able to select the value for the BU, Team,Level, Product and Channel. Also, on selecting BU the teams should get updated and so on. Please suggest.

```
class Master_Table(models.Model):
    Key_Variable=models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    BU = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Team = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Level = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Product= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Channel = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Following is the view

```
def index(request):
    queryset=Master_Table.obects.all()
    context={ "object_list" : queryset }
    return render(request,'compmixapp/index.html',context)
```

HTML

```
  <form>
    <input list="BU" name="BU"> <br /> <br>
      <datalist id="BU">
        <option value={% for obj in object_list %}
                      {{obj.BU}}
                      {% endfor %}
        >
  </form>
```

Comment: Look into [`datalist`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_list.asp) html tag

Comment: already did. How to render the values from django to html is the issue in that case

Comment: Pass these values in `context` variable of the response, and populate the template using it

Comment: So i would suggest to look into form wizards. If the next options should be build by the previous selection, the topic can get really fast really complex. Make multiple templates and set up your logic. If you want to do it good, look into ajax calls and try to generate the next fields  on the fly

Comment: @anuj : so here is what I have tried to do..                                                       
    def index(request):
    queryset=Master_Table.obects.all()
    context={
    "queryset" : queryset
    }
    return render(request,'compmixapp/index.html',context)                                              So when I am trying to pass this into html context tag  list doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Could you edit the question and help us by showing the html template

Comment: @Anuj : updated

Comment: @anuj : The code that I shared works now, however I am not able to see all the values in the dropdown of the form for BU. So the selection only allows me to use the first value from the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes and the way you have defined the `for loop` is semantically wrong.

Change your HTML to following

```
<form>
    <input list="BU" name="BU"><br/><br>
        <datalist id="BU">
        {% for obj in object_list %}
        <option value="{{obj.BU}}">
        {% endfor %}
</form>
```

The issue which is resulting in showing only one value for the options is following part, which is syntactically correct, but semantically wrong, generating different result than you expect.

```
 <option value={% for obj in object_list %}
                  {{obj.BU}}
                  {% endfor %}
    >
```

The Thing that is happing here is, the `datalist` only gets one value which is all the values in the querylist being passed to it.

To elaborate further, lets say the queryset for `Master_Table` returns `a, b, c, d` objects. So the loop you wrote would generate the following HTML

```
<form>
    <input list="BU" name="BU"><br/><br>
        <datalist id="BU">
            <option value=a.BU b.BU c.BU d.BU>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked. Possible to guide me on the dynamic filtering? So once I select the BU, the teams only under that BU should be reported only and so on...

Comment: You might need to make a few queries in the view to achieve it.
Its pretty much difficult to just solve your doubts over comments, Like @N. Ivanov suggested it would be better if you go through few tutorials, preferably video tutorials. Just go over youtube or google the tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the choices within your models.py

Example with `BU`, can be done for all your properties.

```
BU_CHOICES = (
    ('val','displayName'),
    ('val2', 'displayName2'),
    ('val3','displayName3'),
)

class Master_Table(models.Model):
    BU = models.CharField(choices=BU_CHOICES, default='val')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but how do this dynamically filter the values for Team? Also, I am unable to render them to html view

Comment: @deepak in this case I would suggest you to go over some django tutorials, and read over the docs. I would have to write you the complete solution in order to explain what and where, and sorry but I do not have time for that. Hope that helps!

Comment: Any links that you would like to suggest?

Comment: @deepak [Tango with Django](https://leanpub.com/tangowithdjango19/) is a nice free tutorial which has most of the core things, and will help you better to understand what is where, and how you can figure things out on your own. It is for 1.9/1.10 but the examples and tutorial should work fine with 1.11. The download is on the left side (Read Free Sample). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I will go through it. I think what you suggested above, when I tried doing that I can not do filters as I suggested I want to do. I think it will also fetch all the values so it seems I will have to calculate the nex variables on the fly.